# Error on ADAL authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, office365, adal

```
var outlookServicesClient = await AuthenticationHelper.EnsureOutlookServicesClientCreatedAsync("Calendar");


internal static async Task<OutlookServicesClient> EnsureOutlookServicesClientCreatedAsync(string capabilityName)
{
    var signInUserId = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
    var userObjectId = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;

    AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(SettingsHelper.Authority, new ADALTokenCache(signInUserId));

    try
    {
        DiscoveryClient discClient = new DiscoveryClient(SettingsHelper.DiscoveryServiceEndpointUri,
            async () =>
            {
                var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(SettingsHelper.DiscoveryServiceResourceId,                                                             new ClientCredential(SettingsHelper.ClientId, SettingsHelper.ClientSecret),
                        new UserIdentifier(userObjectId, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));

                return authResult.AccessToken;
            });

            var dcr = await discClient.DiscoverCapabilityAsync(capabilityName);

            return new OutlookServicesClient(dcr.ServiceEndpointUri,
                async () =>
                {
                    var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(dcr.ServiceResourceId,
                        new ClientCredential(SettingsHelper.ClientId, SettingsHelper.ClientSecret),
                        new UserIdentifier(userObjectId, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));
                    return authResult.AccessToken;
                });
    }
    catch (AdalException exception)
    {
        //Handle token acquisition failure
        if (exception.ErrorCode == AdalError.FailedToAcquireTokenSilently)
        {
            authContext.TokenCache.Clear();
            throw exception;
        }
        return null;
    } 
    public ADALTokenCache(string user)
    {
        // associate the cache to the current user of the web app
        User = user;
        this.AfterAccess = AfterAccessNotification;
        this.BeforeAccess = BeforeAccessNotification;
        this.BeforeWrite = BeforeWriteNotification;

        // look up the entry in the DB
        Cache = db.UserTokenCacheList.FirstOrDefault(c => c.webUserUniqueId == User);
        // place the entry in memory
        this.Deserialize((Cache == null) ? null : Cache.cacheBits);
    }
```

i am using this code for ADAL authentication. This is working fine in my local IIS server. When i hosted the same on AZURE VM then getting an error like

"Failed to acquire token silently. Call method AcquireToken". Can anybody help me on resolving this error??

Settings Helper code as follows. In public ADALTokenCache(string user) we are getting userid finely but getting an empty cache... What will be the reason??

```
AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(SettingsHelper.Authority, new ADALTokenCache(signInUserId));

        try
        {
            DiscoveryClient discClient = new DiscoveryClient(SettingsHelper.DiscoveryServiceEndpointUri,
                async () =>
                {
                    var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(SettingsHelper.DiscoveryServiceResourceId,
                                                                               new ClientCredential(SettingsHelper.ClientId,
                                                                                                    SettingsHelper.ClientSecret),
                                                                               new UserIdentifier(userObjectId,
                                                                                                  UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));

                    return authResult.AccessToken;
                });
```

Comment: i checked below url , but don't have any solution. so can you suggest any solution for it??https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/92438173-df6e-47ec-92f4-3cadf61b067a/azure-ad-failed-to-acquire-token-silently?forum=WindowsAzureAD

Comment: did u check this already https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-ASPNETMVC-Start/issues/28

Comment: No solution in that link as well. In local mechine it works perfectly but when i hosted in azure VM getting issue. Token is not refreshing i think.

Comment: so all the necessary permissions are given is it ?

Comment: Yes, i gave all permissions

Comment: what's your SettingsHelper.DiscoveryServiceResourceId and SettingsHelper.Authority? Some work for AcquireTokenByAuthorization(),AcquireToken() not for AcquireTokenSilent().

Comment: Please check the original post , I updated settingshelper.authority code as well. I tried AcquireTokenAsync instead of AcquireTokenSilentAsync but not worked out.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your authority does not contain "common". Also, please turn on the diagnostics as explained in http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2015/08/07/adal-diagnostics/ and take a look at the trace. Very often this is due to a mismatch in the cache - acquiretokensilent only works with cached tokens, and if you didn't seed the cache/you are not working against the cache instance you selected earlier/you pass a different user identifier/you pass common as authority you'll get a cache miss.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you were using the O365-ASPNETMVC-Start project on Github.

What's the "**ida:TenantId**" setting in your web.config file on Azure VM?

I can get the same error "Failed to acquire token silently. Call method AcquireToken" if setting the "ida:TenantId" to "**common**". For this scenerio, you need to set "ida:TenantId" to actual tenant id. For example, "**e07xxxx0e-fxx2-441f-ad9a-9dxxa59xxx52**" (guid).

Comment: `<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="ida:ClientId" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
    <add key="ida:ClientSecret" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
    <add key="ida:TenantId" value="fxxxxx0-axxc-4ac5-aa19-c34eeeef7b" />
    <add key="ida:Domain" value="mydomain.com" />
    <add key="ida:AADInstance" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/" />
  </appSettings>`

Comment: Above is the settings in web.config file , Can you check it once and suggest changes if i am wrong..

Comment: Have you tried to call "http#//your_site/Account/RefreshSession" to refresh the ssesion? (replace '#' with ':').